# expression of non-boolean type specified when merging?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code to create a stored procedure, but I seem to be getting a lot of errors below this line:

```
ON (Target.Email = Source.Email AND Target.PromoName = Source.PromoName)
```

The error on this line is "expression of non-boolean type specified". 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].InsertUpdateBasicPromoEntry
    @Email nvarchar(100)
    ,@PromoName varchar(100)
    ,@MaxEntries tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE [dbo].[BasicCodePromoEntries] AS Target
    USING (
        SELECT 
            @Email as Email
        ,@PromoName as PromoName
    ) AS Source
    ON (Target.Email = Source.Email AND Target.PromoName = Source.PromoName)
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        BEGIN
        IF Target.PeriodExpires < GETDATE()
            BEGIN
                UPDATE SET 
                    Target.PeriodExpires = GETDATE()
                    ,Target.PeriodEntries = 1
            END
        ELSE IF Target.PeriodExpires > GETDATE() AND Target.PeriodEntries < @MaxEntries
            BEGIN
                UPDATE SET
                    Target.PeriodEntries = Target.PeriodEntries + 1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RETURN 1
            END 
        RETURN 0
        END
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target
    THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Target (Email, PromoName, PeriodEntries, PeriodExpires) VALUES (@Email, @PromoName, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()))
            RETURN 0
        END

END
```

PS: Every BEGIN and END is underlined, saying, incorrect syntax near...

Comment: I don't think that you can use `IF..ELSE` there

Comment: Also, the `DATETIME()` function doesn't exists in SQL Server

Comment: Woops mixing languages, but why cant I use IF ELSE here?

Comment: I think you'll need to rewrite so you just have a single update/insert after each merge condition, and control what gets updated using case statements for the column values. The syntax is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx